# The column '30' was specified multiple times for 'stat'

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am facing this error on executing query
The column '30' was specified multiple times for 'stat'.

````
FROM Probale
--WHERE     (EntryDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate)
ORDER BY EntryDate

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate), 112)
                + ']','[' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate), 112) + ']')
FROM    #Dates24
ORDER BY EntryDate


DECLARE  @qry NVARCHAR(4000) =
N'SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ItemMasterFile.Descriptionitem,Probale.prdqty, 
DATEPART(DAY, Probale.EntryDate)as DDate
FROM Probale  Inner Join ItemMasterFile on Probale.Codeitem=ItemMasterFile.Codeitem )prd
PIVOT (Sum(prdqty) FOR DDate IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat 
'
-- Executing the query

EXEC(@qry)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names should be unique. You can try this for column names.

```
SELECT  @cols = @cols + ',' + QUOTENAME( CONVERT(varchar(2),EntryDate) )
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT  DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate) AS EntryDate FROM #Dates24 ) T
ORDER BY EntryDate

SET @cols =  STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Serkan Arslan , Store procedure is executed but result is not coming ,,

Comment: Does your sub query return any data?

Comment: @akhterHussain I tried the query with my own tables and it looks working correctly.

Comment: it now working just adding COALESCE(@cols + ',','') ,but my date filter parameter is not perfectly working ,means that if i give current month date,then previous month data also coming,please guide,,thanks

Comment: You should combine month and day numbers for column names and subquery. For example you can write `CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, EntryDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST( DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate) AS VARCHAR(2))`  instead of `DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate)`